# How to load a uibutton in a table inside a uiWebVIew

Tags: html, xcode, uiwebview

Using a uiwebview, I need to have a table in which I create a text field taking place in the left td and a uibutton in the right one. 
Now this button is already created statically and now I need to set it's position according to the right td of this new table.
So my question is basically how can I set the position of the uibutton to be in the right td of a table
Any ideas will be highly appreciated

Comment: For clarity... you want a UIButton to be rendered in a position which is aware of the rendered HTML contents of a UIWebView?

Comment: yes i want it to be rendered in an html table row

Comment: My $0.02: Without resorting to ugly trickery which only approximates what you are asking for, you'll need to use HTML in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a character counting method with a certain ratio used to put the button next to the word...its not the best solution never..but it got the job done!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact positions of the elements in the web page you can create an overlay view and put the button there, pass all other events to the UIWebView, but that's really a a dirty solution.

Comment: The webView Elements are strings and every time they have a different length , now i know the position of the button because i created statically, but i dunno how can i set its position to be in a table, right td

Comment: Well, if you know where you want the button you can programatically set its coordinates. Use `button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, length)` to define where you want it. You would need to extract from the table where the button needs to be located.